# What is behavior of that integral?

Tags: calculus

Does the improper integral $$\int\limits_{2\pi}^\infty \frac {\sin x} {\cos x +\ln x}\,dx $$ converge or diverge?
The Maple code $$VectorCalculus:-int(sin(x)/(cos(x)+ln(x)), x = Pi .. infinity, numeric, epsilon = .1) $$ says nothing about that.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B2%5Cpi%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D+%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin+x%7D%7B%5Ccos+x+%2B%5Cln+x%7D+dx) agrees with Maple. Looking [the plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%5Cfrac%7B%5Csin+x%7D%7B%5Ccos+x+%2B%5Cln+x%7D%2C+x%3D2*pi..100), it looks like the integral converges and equals $0$.

Comment: It converges for reasons similar to those of [Leibniz's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) and [Dirichlet's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test).

Comment: @Lucian: Can you kindly give an answer, not a suggestion? The similar "answer" was recently deleted by the author.

Comment: All integrals are $\big($Riemann$\big)$ sums, so, roughly speaking, whatever is true of series, holds for them as well. E.g., Stolz-Cesaro is for discrete sums what l'Hopital's rule is for continuous ones. Write the corresponding Riemann sum of your integral, and then apply either one of the two similar criteria listed above inside the limit sign.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let

$$I_m = \int_{m\pi}^{(m+1)\pi} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x + \ln x}\,dx.$$

Since $\ln x \to\infty$ for $x\to \infty$, we have $I_m\xrightarrow{m\to\infty} 0$. Furthermore, $I_m = (-1)^m\lvert I_m\rvert$.

Now it remains to check the monotonicity of $\lvert I_m\rvert$. We have

$$
\lvert I_{m-1}\rvert - \lvert I_{m}\rvert
= \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin t}{\cos (m\pi-t) + \ln (m\pi-t)}\,dt - \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin t}{\cos (m\pi+t)+\ln (m\pi+t)}\,dt
$$

and since

$$\bigl(\cos (m\pi+t)+\ln (m\pi+t)\bigr) - \bigl(\cos (m\pi-t)+\ln(m\pi-t)\bigr) = \ln (m\pi+t) - \ln (m\pi-t) > 0,$$

the monotonicity of $\lvert I_m\rvert$ follows. Now Leibniz' criterion says

$$\sum_{m=2}^\infty I_m$$

converges, and since $I_m\to 0$, we also deduce the existence of

$$\lim_{T\to\infty} \int_{2\pi}^T \frac{\sin x}{\cos x+\ln x}\,dx.$$

If $2k\pi \leqslant T \leqslant (2k+1)\pi$, then

$$\sum_{m=2}^{2k-1} I_m \leqslant \sum_{m=2}^{2k-1} I_m + \int_{2k\pi}^T \frac{\sin x}{\cos x+\ln x}\,dx = \int_{2\pi}^T\frac{\sin x}{\cos x+\ln x}\,dx \leqslant \sum_{m=2}^{2k} I_m,$$

and similarly, if $(2k+1)\pi \leqslant T \leqslant (2k+2)\pi$, then

$$\sum_{m=2}^{2k} I_m \geqslant \sum_{m=2}^{2k} I_m + \int_{(2k+1)\pi}^T \frac{\sin x}{\cos x+\ln x}\,dx = \int_{2\pi}^T \frac{\sin x}{\cos x+\ln x}\,dx \geqslant \sum_{m=2}^{2k+1} I_m.$$

Letting $S_n = \sum\limits_{m=2}^n I_m$, we have $S_2 > S_4 > \dotsc > S_{2k} > S_{2k+2} > S_{2k+3} > S_{2k+1} > \dotsc > S_3$, and hence

$$S_{2k-1} \leqslant \int_{2\pi}^T \frac{\sin x}{\cos x+\ln x}\,dx \leqslant S_{2k}$$

whenever $T \geqslant 2k\pi$. Therefore

$$\left\lvert \int_{T_1}^{T_2} \frac{\sin x}{\cos x+\ln x}\,dx\right\rvert \leqslant S_{2k} - S_{2k-1} = I_{2k}$$

whenever $T_1,T_2 \geqslant 2k\pi$.

Comment: @ Daniel Fisher: Can you kindly state the last step in detail?

Comment: That the convergence of the integral (as an improper Riemann integral) follows from the convergence of the sum?

Comment: Yes. Exactly this.

Comment: @user64494 Done. If anything remains unclear, ask.

Answer (score 0):

The denominator is positive for all $x \in [2 \pi,\infty)$, since $\ln(x) > 1 \geq |\cos(x)|$ for $x>e$ and $2 \pi > e$. The numerator alternates in sign at each multiple of $\pi$. So the integral can be written as

$$\int_{2 \pi}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x) + \ln(x)} dx = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \int_{k \pi}^{(k+1) \pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x) + \ln(x)} dx$$

For even $k$, the numerator is positive, so we get a positive term; for odd $k$, the numerator is negative, so we get a negative term. Then you apply the alternating series test as Lucian suggested.

Comment: A similar "argument": $$\int_0^\infty \sin x\, dx= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{2k \pi}^{(2k+2)\pi} \sin x\, dx=0.$$